# How I can prove that this function is bounded or not

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How I can prove that this function is bounded or not
$$f(u,v,w)=-v±\sqrt { w+u²+v²-uv-1}$$

Comment: What is the domain of definition?

Comment: @CameronBuie: All $ℝ³$.

Comment: Well, that isn't really true, even if you mean $\Bbb R^3.$ What is $f(0,0,0),$ for example? However, if there are no restrictions on $(u,v,w),$ except that we must have $(u,v,w)\in\Bbb R^3$ such that $f(u,v,w)\in\Bbb R,$ then (following Igor Rivin's suggestion) we can easily see that $f$ is unbounded, simply by fixing $u=v=0$ and letting $w$ grow sufficiently large.

Comment: @CameronBuie: What happen if $|u|≤α,|v|≤β,|w|≤δ$.

Comment: Hmmm...this is growing too long for a comment. I will convert to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fix $u=v=0,$ and then see what happens when $w=10^{10}.$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "It depends."

First of all, in order to be a function, we need to have *one* function value per valid input. As written, though, we have (for example) that $f(1,1,1)=-1\pm 1,$ so your function $f$ is not well-defined, as written. I will assume instead that you wish the rule to be $$f(u,v,w)=-v+\sqrt{w+u^2+v^2-uv-1}.$$

Second of all, note that domain is a very important information to give when defining a function. So, if (for example) your domain is $$D:=\bigl\{(u,v,w)\in\Bbb R^3\mid w+u^2+v^2-uv-1\ge 0,\bigr\},$$ then we can simply follow Igor Rivin's suggestion, fixing $u=v=1$ and allowing $w$ to grow without bound, thereby showing that $f(u,v,w)$ can be as large as we like.

If, on the other hand, we were dealing with a smaller domain, say $$D\cap\{(u,v,w)\mid |u|\le\alpha,|v|\le\beta,|w|\le\delta\}$$ for some real $\alpha,\beta,\delta,$ then the domain is compact, so the image is compact (as the continuous image of a compact set), and so the image is bounded.